# Getting word embeddings for your dataset using training data in glove

Tags: python, macos, nlp

I recently installed gensim and glove in my mac and am trying to get word embedding for textual data I have. However, I'm having trouble finding the right function for it. I've only come across methods to get similarity metrics between two words. How do I train a glove object with data present in the library and use it to obtain embeddings for words in my dataset? Or is there any other library in python to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the format of glove is different from word2vec you can convert the format of glove to word2vec format using this https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.html

Let the converted glove is glove_changed.txt

`import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('glove_changed.txt', binary=False)
print(model['cat']) // This will give the wordvector for the word 'cat'`

Comment: May I know what you mean by converted glove?

Comment: @Sanj That is nothing but the glove vectors file converted to the word2vec format which is generated from the tutorial in the link above.